# How to configure The facebook canvas application for Mobile site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas, facebook-php-sdk

I have developed a canvas app and I dont have a mobile site right now.So How can i set the canvas page url for both mobile devices and desktop?

Do i need to change the code of the app? Because If I set same url for the both, It Throws error "The app is misconfigured for mobile devices"

So, How to configure the mobile url?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your App settings, add an URL to the "Mobile Site URL" input field, right where you specified your Canvas URL.

Make sure it is an external URL (NOT apps.facebook.com/...) and make sure you don´t redirect to apps.facebook.com on that URL.

Comment: yes I have added the same url there but It shows "The mobile version of the app xxxxxxx is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access.

Comment: so what are your settings for canvas then?

Comment: Here is my canvas settings https://www.dropbox.com/s/dmhkueppt9bqspo/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-16%20at%206.48.33%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: not sure why you directly show a login screen, don´t do that. it´s annoying for users if they don´t even know what to expect in your app. show some information, present a login button, let the user decide. may be the reason why it does not work on mobile, who knows. either way, use FB.login to authorize users, it´s much better usability.

Comment: in other words: don´t redirect

Comment: Did you miss something? what are you talking about? The app is  for some group members who can attend extam test and I am not showing any login screen to them.

Comment: i opened that url in my browser and immediately got redirected to the login screen. you should remove that app in your settings and try without being logged in.

Comment: You are right. I made a different page for mobile that redirect user perfectly.